# Oauth Authentication in Logic Apps

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps

How can you authenticate an HTTP Request to Logic Apps using Oauth Authentication mechanism? Any Ideas and pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old topic but in case anyone stumbled upon this challenge then the high level answer is

1. Create API management
2. Add VIP (Virtual IP) of API management to Logic App Firewall
3. Add OAuth token policy in API management
4. Add remove Authorization header policy in API management
5. Optionally add extract claim policy expression to pass caller details to Logic App for extra logic

If you are interested I have this in very detail explained on my blog https://marczak.io/posts/2019/08/secure-logic-app-with-api-management/

Comment: Nice answer, but is there anyway to do it in logic apps, without adding APIM ?

Comment: Unfortunately not @SteveC

Answer (score 1):

I believe as of now (2020-12-11), you can use Active Directory OAuth to make a call to a Logic App HTTP trigger

I had to add an Azure Active Directory authorization policy with an Issuer claim of `https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>`

My test logic app could then make the request using a HTTP action with the authentication type set to "Active Directory OAuth", the authority set to `https://login.microsoftonline.com`, the audience set to `https://management.azure.com` and client ID and secret from an App Registration

Answer (score 0):

Request trigger only supports SAS key, you can, however, put the endpoint behind API Management which will allow you to Oauth.

Comment: But, of course, the HTTP trigger with SAS key still exists, so a client who knows the SAS-enabled url could bypass API Management...

Comment: Logic Apps support IP whitelisting, so if you do decide to put the Logic App endpoint behind API-M, you can whitelist only API-M IPs and no other callers can invoke said Logic App even if they know the SAS key.

Comment: Also, Oauth request trigger is on our backlog, no ETA at the moment though.

Comment: How can I restrict to APIM IP addresses? Can I restrict to just my instance?

Comment: @Josh correct. In Logic Apps page, find "Access control configuration (will soon be called "workflow settings")". Select "specific IP range" and fill in the IPs for your API-M instance.